# Jacobian of kinematic IMU Model

Tags: kinematics, kalman-filter, dynamics, motion, jacobian

I have the following problem: given two Input Vectors $x = \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\v_x\\v_y\\v_z\\q_1\\q_2\\q_3\\q_4\end{pmatrix}$, $u = \begin{pmatrix}a_x\\a_y\\a_z\\w_x\\w_y\\w_z\end{pmatrix}$ time $t$ and gravity $g$ calculate  $\dot{x}$. These vectors contain values recorded from an IMU.

for $\dot{x}$ I simply considered the motions of equation:
$\dot{x} = f(x,u) = \begin{pmatrix}a_x*t+v_x\\a_y*t+v_y\\a_z*t+v_z\\a_x\\a_y+g\\a_z\\\dot{q_1}\\\dot{q_2}\\\dot{q_3}\\\dot{q_4}\end{pmatrix}$. 
Any $\dot{q_i}$ is calculated using a given Formula which is okay so far

Is my IMU-Model for $x$ and $\dot{x}$ correct?
I need to calculate the Jacobian $A=\frac{\partial \dot{x}}{\partial x} $.

I dont really get to calculate $A$. it has to be $A \in \mathbb{R}^{10x10}$.
But i always fail at calculating it, especially with respect to the quaternions.

My First 6 Lines look like that:

$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0 & 0 & a_x & 0 & 0 & ? & ? & ? & ?\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_y & 0 & ? & ? & ? & ?\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_z & ? & ? & ? & ?\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ? & ? & ? & ?\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ? & ? & ? & ?\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ? & ? & ? & ?\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ? & ? & ? & ?\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ? & ? & ? & ?\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ? & ? & ? & ?\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ? & ? & ? & ?\\  
\end{array} } \right] $

Thanks for the help!

:EDIT:

As i just found out, any derivative $\frac{\partial \dot{q}}{\partial q}=0$. So i guess its:

$A=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0 & 0 & a_x & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_y & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_z & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array} } \right]$ ?

Answer (score 1):

A [robot Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_kinematics#Robot_Jacobian) is

> The time derivative of the kinematics equations  [...] which relates the joint rates to the linear and angular velocity of the end-effector.

I'll emphasize that it

> relates the **joint rates** to the linear and angular velocity of the **end-effector**.

You give *no information* about a physical configuration, joints, or where the IMU is located. You give *no information* about what you're trying to do with the Jacobian.

You ask if your IMU model is correct, but then say, *"any $\dot{q}_i$ is calculated using a given Formula which is okay so far."* What is the formula? If it's working, then *what is the question?*

For the linear speed terms, you're failing to take into account the linear speed caused by rotation -

$$
v = \omega \times r \\
$$

It's also not clear what your terms are. You have $a_N$ - are these accelerometer readings? I ask because you have $\dot{v}_y = a_y + g$. This *only works* if $g$ is exactly colinear with the y-axis. Is this the case? **No**, unless your IMU is always perfectly level. Otherwise, you're going to need to apply a rotation matrix somewhere - either to rotate gravity to the local frame, or to rotate the local measurements (IMU measurements) to the global frame.